# Overload method for unique_ptr and shared_ptr is ambiguous with polymorphism

Tags: c++, c++14, overloading, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

Coding stuff after taking the hint from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444116/ownership-with-a-physical-representation)'s answer, I ran into an issue with overloading Scene::addObject.

To reiterate the relevant bits and make this self contained, with the least details possible:

- I have a hierarchy of objects inheriting from `Interface` of which there are `Foo`s and `Bar`s;
- I have a `Scene` which owns these objects;
- `Foo`s are to be `unique_ptr`s and `Bar`s are to be `shared_ptr`s in my main (for reasons explained in the previous question);
- the `main` passes them to the `Scene` instance, which takes ownership.

Minimal code example is [this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbd879ab9d4beb69):

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

class Interface
{
public:
  virtual ~Interface() = 0;
};

inline Interface::~Interface() {}

class Foo : public Interface
{
};

class Bar : public Interface
{
};

class Scene
{
public:
  void addObject(std::unique_ptr<Interface> obj);
//  void addObject(std::shared_ptr<Interface> obj);
};

void Scene::addObject(std::unique_ptr<Interface> obj)
{
}

//void Scene::addObject(std::shared_ptr<Interface> obj)
//{
//}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  auto scn = std::make_unique<Scene>();

  auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo>();
  scn->addObject(std::move(foo));

//  auto bar = std::make_shared<Bar>();
//  scn->addObject(bar);
}
```

Uncommenting the commented lines results in:

```
error: call of overloaded 'addObject(std::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<Foo, std::default_delete<Foo> >&>::type)' is ambiguous

   scn->addObject(std::move(foo));

                                ^

main.cpp:27:6: note: candidate: 'void Scene::addObject(std::unique_ptr<Interface>)'

 void Scene::addObject(std::unique_ptr<Interface> obj)

      ^~~~~

main.cpp:31:6: note: candidate: 'void Scene::addObject(std::shared_ptr<Interface>)'

 void Scene::addObject(std::shared_ptr<Interface> obj)

      ^~~~~
```

Uncommenting the shared and commenting the unique stuff also compiles, so I take it the problem is, like the compiler says, in the overload. However I need the overload as both these types will need to be stored in some kind of collection, and they are indeed kept as pointers to base (possibly all moved into `shared_ptr`s).

I'm passing both by-value because I want to make clear I'm taking ownership in `Scene` (and upping the reference counter for the `shared_ptr`s). Not really clear to me where the issue lies at all, and I couldn't find any example of this elsewhere.

Comment: Converting from `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` to `std::shared_ptr<Scene>` is as good as converting to `std::unique_ptr<Scene>`.

Comment: Nice MCVE, nice question. I'd like to see more of those.

Comment: For me if class accepts two different kind of pointers for the same base class is a code smell. This means that something bad happens with memory management inside that class. So to fix it I would remove one of the methods.  Probably the `unique_ptr` version is obsolete since there is easy conversion to `shared_ptr`. Other way to fix the issue is do not use overload (rename at least one of the methods) what should improve readability.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is this constructor of [`shared_ptr` (13)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), (which is not explicit), is as good a match as a similar "moving derived to base" constructor of [`unique_ptr` (6)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) (also not explicit).

```
template< class Y, class Deleter > 
shared_ptr( std::unique_ptr<Y,Deleter>&& r ); // (13)
```

> 13) Constructs a `shared_ptr` which manages the object currently managed by `r`. The deleter associated with `r` is stored for future deletion of the managed object. `r` manages no object after the call.
>
> This overload doesn't participate in overload resolution if `std::unique_ptr<Y, Deleter>::pointer` is not compatible with `T*`. If `r.get()` is a null pointer, this overload is equivalent to the default constructor (1).   (since C++17)

```
template< class U, class E >
unique_ptr( unique_ptr<U, E>&& u ) noexcept; //(6)
```

> 6) Constructs a `unique_ptr` by transferring ownership from `u` to `*this`, where `u` is constructed with a specified deleter (E).
>
> This constructor only participates in overload resolution if all of the following is true:
>
> a) `unique_ptr<U, E>::pointer` is implicitly convertible to pointer
>
> b) `U` is not an array type
>
> c) Either `Deleter` is a reference type and `E` is the same type as `D`, or `Deleter` is not a reference type and `E` is implicitly convertible to `D`

In the non polymorphic case, you are constructing a `unique_ptr<T>` from a `unique_ptr<T>&&`, which uses the non-template move constructor. There overload resolution prefers the non-template

---

I'm going to assume that `Scene` stores `shared_ptr<Interface>`s. In that case you don't need to overload `addObject` for `unique_ptr`, you can just allow the implicit conversion in the call.

Comment: Why it's not ambiguous without polymorphism?

Comment: @snake_style clarified. Move constructor was a misnomer

Comment: I mean struct D
{
};
void func(shared_ptr<D> ptr){}
void func(unique_ptr<D> ptr){}

int main()
{
    auto p = make_unique<D>();
    func(std::move(p));
}
Why those ctor don't called here in this sample?

Comment: @snake_style in that case, you don't have a template constructor selected for `unique_ptr`, but the non-template move constructor. Overload resolution prefers non-template conversions

Answer (score 5):

The other answer explains the ambiguity and a possible solution. Here's another way in case you end up needing both overloads; you can always add another parameter in such cases to break the ambiguity and use tag-dispatching. The boiler-plate code is hidden in private part of `Scene`:

```
class Scene
{
    struct unique_tag {};
    struct shared_tag {};
    template<typename T> struct tag_trait;
    // Partial specializations are allowed in class scope!
    template<typename T, typename D> struct tag_trait<std::unique_ptr<T,D>> { using tag = unique_tag; };
    template<typename T>             struct tag_trait<std::shared_ptr<T>>   { using tag = shared_tag; };

  void addObject_internal(std::unique_ptr<Interface> obj, unique_tag);
  void addObject_internal(std::shared_ptr<Interface> obj, shared_tag);

public:
    template<typename T>
    void addObject(T&& obj)
    {
        addObject_internal(std::forward<T>(obj),
            typename tag_trait<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::tag{});
    }
};
```

Full compilable example is [here.](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55e5fc948ab599e3)

Answer (score 3):

You have declared two overloads, one taking `std::unique_ptr<Interface>` and one taking `std::shared_ptr<Interface>` but are passing in a parameter of type `std::unique_ptr<Foo>`. As none of your functions match directly the compiler has to perform a conversion to call your function.

There is one conversion available to `std::unique_ptr<Interface>` (simple type conversion to unique pointer to base class) and another to `std::shared_ptr<Interface>` (change to a shared pointer to the base class). These conversions have the same priority so the compiler doesn't know which conversion to use so your functions are ambiguous.

If you pass `std::unique_ptr<Interface>` or `std::shared_ptr<Interface>` there is no conversion required so there is no ambiguity.

The solution is to simply remove the `unique_ptr` overload and always convert to `shared_ptr`. This assumes that the two overloads have the same behaviour, if they don't renaming one of the methods could be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by jrok is already quite good. The following approach allows to reuse code even better:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace internal {
    template <typename S, typename T>
    struct smart_ptr_rebind_trait {};

    template <typename S, typename T, typename D>
    struct smart_ptr_rebind_trait<S,std::unique_ptr<T,D>> { using rebind_t = std::unique_ptr<S>; };

    template <typename S, typename T>
    struct smart_ptr_rebind_trait<S,std::shared_ptr<T>> { using rebind_t = std::shared_ptr<S>; };

}

template <typename S, typename T>
using rebind_smart_ptr_t = typename internal::smart_ptr_rebind_trait<S,std::remove_reference_t<T>>::rebind_t;

class Interface
{
public:
  virtual ~Interface() = 0;
};

inline Interface::~Interface() {}

class Foo : public Interface {};

class Bar : public Interface {};

class Scene
{
  void addObject_internal(std::unique_ptr<Interface> obj) { std::cout << "unique\n"; }

  void addObject_internal(std::shared_ptr<Interface> obj) { std::cout << "shared\n"; }

public:

  template<typename T>
  void addObject(T&& obj) {
    using S = rebind_smart_ptr_t<Interface,T>;
    addObject_internal( S(std::forward<T>(obj)) );
  }   
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  auto scn = std::make_unique<Scene>();

  auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo>();
  scn->addObject(std::move(foo));

  auto bar = std::make_shared<Bar>();
  scn->addObject(bar); // ok
}
```

What we do here is to first introduce some helper classes that allow to rebind smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> Foos are to be unique_ptrs and Bars are to be shared_ptrs in my main (for reasons explained in the previous question);

Can you overload in terms of pointer-to-`Foo` and pointer-to-`Bar` instead of pointer-to-`Interface`, since you want to treat them differently ?